# How to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing on my mobile app (cordova) that hooks up to an API (in Yii)

Tags: javascript, php, yii, cross-domain, cors

I have implemented a mobile cordova app (from another external developer) into my local web environment that works inconjunction with a RESTful API system that I have developed.

I am trying to login, this passes the JSON request to my API with the username & password and basically returns a response.

In Mozilla Firefore I get the following response within the console log :-

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mystickers.local/myStickersApi/V1/appLogin.
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Can anyone provide the best/simplest way to enable Cross Origin Requestion Sharing, my API is developed using Yii 1.x.x (e.g PHP) and the mobile app is developed using the Cordova framework (a combination of HTML5/CSS & javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following block of code to my API just before the json content is echo'd out

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");
```

Seems to work now :)

Comment: Saved my life!! Thanks

Comment: @MaycowMoura I think saving your life maybe a little dramatic lol But I am glad the snippet of code helped you I get enough help from this site and it is nice to help others in return

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a bit more detail to this answer?